# How to run a robot framework testcase, in parallel across two different devices

Tags: robotframework

Following robot framework testcase is to do:

STEP 1: Telnet into HOST1 and do image upgrade

STEP 2: Telnet into HOST2 and do image upgrade

```
***Settings***

Library  Telnet

*** Variables ***

${HOST1}                1.1.1.1
${HOST2}                1.1.1.2
${USERNAME}             admin
${PASSWORD}             test

***Test Cases***

testcase1

    Open Connection         ${HOST1}
    Login   ${USERNAME}     ${PASSWORD}
    Write                   enable
    Write                   upgrade tftp://10.1.1.1/image.img
    ${data1}                Read Until Regexp       .*#
    Open Connection         ${HOST2}
    Login   ${USERNAME}     ${PASSWORD}
    Write                   enable
    Write                   upgrade tftp://10.1.1.1/image.img
    ${data1}                Read Until Regexp       .*#
```

This is working fine. But the problem is, I am able to do image upgrade to HOST2 only when HOST1 upgrade finishes. But I want to do the image upgrade parallel in both machines.

Is there any way to run HOST1 image upgrade in background and initiate the HOST2 image upgrade?

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1):

One simple trick is to use polling.

```
*** Test Cases ***
testcase1
    Set Default Configuration               prompt=$
    Open Connection                         ${HOST1}       alias=${HOST1}
    Login                                   ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}
    Log                                     start downloading ${HOST1}
    Write                                   wget http://huge_file
    Open Connection                         ${HOST2}       alias=${HOST2}
    Login                                   ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}
    Log    start downloading ${HOST2}
    Write                                   wget http://small_file
    # start polling for 2 min every 10 sec
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds             120 sec        10 sec    isPrompt
    File Should Exist                       huge_file
    File Should Exist                       small file  
    Close All Connections

*** Keywords ***
isPrompt
    Switch Connection    ${HOST1}
    ${passed1}           Run Keyword And Return Status    Read Until Prompt
    Switch Connection    ${HOST2}
    ${passed2}           Run Keyword And Return Status    Read Until Prompt
    ${return}            Set Variable If                  ${passed1}==${True} and    {passed2}==${True}    ${True}    ${False}
    # keyword only succeeds if both connections have prompt again
    Should Be True       ${return}
```

It should be also possible to use *Read Until Regexp* instead of *Read Until Prompt*

Comment: Still upgrade not happens in parallel. The idea that you gave is to get result at once using polling and prompt. This is the great idea. But my problem is i need to run both upgrade in parallel. Any clue please?

Comment: The idea is to run into a timeout for each "Read Until ..." as long as result is not reached.
In my example, downloads are started in parallel.

Comment: Afterwards following will happen:
polling every 10 sec 
   connection_1 (downloading): wait for Prompt -> timeout after 3sec -> passed1=False;
   connection_2 (finished): wait for Prompt -> passed2=True
==> Keyword isPrompt not succeeds;
repeat until passed1 & passed2 are True or 2 min timeout.
Maybe you have to  change your timeout value to a shorter time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Yes Now device upgrade happens in parallel. Thanks so much. But I am getting "Evaluating expression 'False==True and' failed: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (<string>, line 1)" error.  Any clue please?

Answer (score 1):

One options is:
Implement a shell or bat script to execute test cases at same time. That mean several robot framework processes are running at same time. Then merge the outputs and generate logs.

for each connection, you could define two variable files for each connection.

```
***Settings***

Library    Telnet

*** Variables ***
${HOST}                1.1.1.1
${USERNAME}             admin
${PASSWORD}             test

***Test Cases***
testcase1

    Open Connection         ${HOST}
    Login   ${USERNAME}     ${PASSWORD}
    Write                   enable
    Write                   upgrade tftp://${HOST}/image.img
    ${data1}                Read Until Regexp    .*#
```

And there is a tool which could execute robot test cases parallel.
https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot